# Could someone explain the logical error in this program?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 5, *p, **q, b;
    p = &a;
    q = p;
    b = *q;
    printf("%d", b);
}
```

I want to find out how these assignations are wrong at the memory level. Suppose the address of `a` is `100`. `p = &a` is a correct assignation. Then `p` will point to the address `100`. I am confused with the statements `q = p` and `b = *q`. How they are wrong?

Comment: `q` should be `q = &p` not `q = p` and `b` should be `b = **q` not `b = *q`.

Answer (score 3):

`p = &a;` is correct. - Assigning the address of `a` to pointer `p`.

`q = p;` is wrong (type conflict). - You attempt to assign a pointer (`*`) to a pointer to pointer (`**`). It should be `q = &p` so that you gain the address of `p` and assign it to the pointer to pointer `q`.

`b = *q;` is wrong (type conflict). - You attempt to assign a pointer (`*q` gains `p`) to an `int` object. It should be `b = **q;` to assign the value of `a` to `b`.

---

If you had compiled this code with a standard-compliant and up-to-date compiler, it would have shown you all the conflicts and had probably answered the most of your questions.

Next time before posting, try to execute your code with a compiler like GCC or Clang and look what it tells you with diagnostic messages.

If you don't want to install a compiler package or IDE on your computer although highly recommended, you can compile it online with [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) or [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/).

The compiler is your best friend in finding syntactic issues. Especially if you use even more help-finding flags like `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-Werror`. :-)

Comment: The second half of this answer is inappropriate. There is no indication OP ignored compiler messages. The OP shows they know the statements are faulty by explicitly acknowledging this in the question. The question asks **how** they are wrong at a “memory level.” Presumably, OP wants to know more about the implementation of pointers and pointers to pointers, not just “these assignments violate type rules.” And this answer does not speak to that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil For me there is a clear indication that OP missed to compile this code, indeed. OP doesn't provided any result messages from a compiler and didn't speak about confusion about those. The diagnostics are pretty clear on that part so that almost no need is to explain them further. If this would have been the case nonetheless, OP would ask for what the messages are meaning but this is not the case here. Instead s/he asked for "*Could someone explain the logical error in this program?*" and "*How they are wrong?*" which could have been clearly answered by the compiler diagnostics.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: the compiler is your best friend if you kindly ask it to point your mistakes... Default settings are way too lenient, extra warnings are still required for proper marks of friendship, you might want to document the simplest: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: @chqrlie Take that into the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`q` is of type `int**` - it's a pointer to pointer. Compiler gives you warnings, because you are assigning value of `p` (type `int*`) to type `int**`.

It should be:

```c
   q=&p;
   b=**q;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a=5,*p,**q,b;    #1
   p=&a;                #2
   q=p;                 #3
   b=*q;                #4
   printf("%d",b);      #5
}
```

1. in *#1*, you have declared integer data type `a` and initialized it to 5. let's assume its address in memory, is `0x100`. `p` is integer pointer and not initialized (some (not all of them) of the compilers today has it as a feature, and initialize it to `NULL`, **but you shouldn't rely on that, and you should initialize it to NULL explicitly !**), `q` is pointer to integer pointer, and non-intialized (the same comment as before), `b` is a non-intialized integer.
2. in *#2*, you are assigning the address of `a` to `p` so now `p` is pointing to `a` in memory. Hence, `p` value is : `0x100`
3. in *#3*, you are assigning `p` (which is `int` pointer) to *pointer to int pointer*! this is wrong, but the compiler will let you pass with the warning: `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`. The fix for this `warning` is, `q=&p;`. since this is only warning, `q` is pointing to `0x100`!
4. `b` is integer, you are assigning it, `*q`, which is `q`'s value, which is `0x100` in this case(you can't assign a memory address to an `int` variable) and it's of type `int pointer`! Again, this is wrong, but the compiler will let you pass with the warning: `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`. You should do `b = **q`. `b`'s value now is : `(*q)` which is `*(&p)` which is `*(0x100)` which is  `5`!
5. prints the value of `b`, hence prints `5`

Comment: Re “compilers today do the work for you and init it to null”: No, they do not, and this is a dangerous statement because it will causes programmers to write software with bugs. Maybe some compilers have this as a feature, but it is certainly not generally true and should not be relied upon absent specific compiler documentation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - i didnt say that. but i will improve my answer. thank you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - fixed. thank. you. can you remove the down vote please ?

Comment: Can you identify a compiler that has this as a feature?

Comment: @EricPostpischil GCC and Clang both set indeterminate SSA values to zero if they are still live at the beginning of the register allocation phase. So for instance `int f(){int x;return x;}` will return zero, if it's not unlined. But this is not a documented feature—I know about it from code inspection—and they both also aggressively optimize, before register allocation, on the assumption that a code path that _uses_ an indeterminate value must be unreachable.

Comment: @Adam Local custom strongly disapproves of asking for votes.

Comment: @zwol: [Clang does not.](https://godbolt.org/z/GssdM6) If it ever did, that’s an example of a reason not to rely on undocumented behavior.

Comment: Why is the explicit `NULL` initialization so important in this case at all? `p` gets immediately assigned by the address of `a` at the next statement.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: It is not important in this code. It is important in what you teach future programmers. If you teach a future programmer that the compiler will initialize an automatic object, and the compiler does not initialize an automatic object, then their future programs will have bugs.

Comment: In this case where we reassign `p` value immediatley after the first line, it is less important but it is a good habbit to initialize pointers in the same line you are declare them. anyway i understand your comment.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it is not strictly relevant and more or less redundant. To give generic lessons isn't needed. It is always a good intent to learn people good things. I have nothing to say against that. But just for the sake of the example, it isn't necessary and might even confuse OP since you explicitly bring it to foreground.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Do you think OP's not confused when he/she was asking a question like this? OP could have prepared and read about pointers before asking a question like this. And you say telling any programmer to explicitly initializing variables in C leads to confusion.

Comment: @Lucas "*And you say telling any programmer to explicitly initializing variables in C leads to confusion.*" - I've never said that and doesn't agree with any of my mindsets. I said it is confusing in the context of the question of the OP as it is irrelevant here. He brought this to focus which is quite unnecessary and diverting from the questions intent. It's a difference.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yeah, I agree with you that it's irrelevant in this case to initialize every variable in this program to NULL. But it won't hurt if anyone tells the OP about variable initialization to NULL as it is a good programming practice in C.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Anyway, everyone has their own way of seeing things. It's totally okay, what you think in this context.